# color changing widget using Qt 5

Tags: qt, colors, widget, qt5

I want to create the following using Qt 5 :-

The interface contains a input box which takes the color input and the box changes color according to the given input

GUI for changing widget color according to input
[image: GUI for changing widget color according to input]

Comment: What have you tried? Or do you want us to do all the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind with `Signals & Slots` the button clicked, then get the text from the `QLineEdit` and set the stylesheet of the `QLabel`. 
If you want help with the code, post your progress or ask for specific code question

Comment: how to make the color changing block. The functions for doing that

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'm assuming you already bind the clicked signal.. Now i'm gonna give you 2 options to deal with the problem:

1°: Trust QColor to make that change (which would make the code easiers but limited to colors that Qt have in the system)The function would be:

```
void MainWindon::on_okButton_clicked()
{
QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();`

ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: 3px solid black; background-color: " + text + "}");
}
```

2°) deal with if statements (which can be really exausting but you have the option to control the colors):

```
void MainWindon::on_okButton_clicked()
{
     QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();`

     if(text == "red")
           ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: 3px solid black; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)}");
     else if(text == "green")
           ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: 3px solid black; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)}");
     else if(text == "blue")
           ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {border: 3px solid black; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255)}");
}
```